# Navigating to a fragment changes URL unexpectedly

Tags: url, uri-fragment

I have a url that looks like:

`localhost:8080/some-resource/id`

And a link that looks like:

```
<a href="#my-section">
    Section
</a>
```

I would have expected that clicking this link would result in a url that looks like this:

`localhost:8080/some-resource/id#my-section`

But instead I'm getting:

`localhost:8080/#my-section`

Is this expected behavior? (By the way, I'm using ReactJS)

Comment: How is react related to this?

Comment: I don't know if it is or isn't, but I thought I'd include that information for the sake of completeness.

Comment: It's better if you create a MCVE for a minimal COMPLETE verifiable example.